# Issue with moving images using relative positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue moving images using relative positioning. Currently, I have 3 images uploaded into my container and only one can be moved via css with relative positioning. The other two, I have tried using the code below to move, but they stay in the same spot.

Thanks for any suggestions!

```
 <img class="first" src="assets/icons/Astro_Letter_Logo.png" alt="Astro Letter Logo" width="100" height="250">
      
      
      <img class="second" src="assets/icons/Mail_It_Button.png" alt="Send It" width="350" height="300">
      
    <img class="third" src="assets/icons/Address_Found!_Click _to_Launch.png" alt="Send It" width="350" height="300">
```

CSS Below

```
img.first {
      position: relative;
      top: -75px; left: -1px;
     
}

img.second {
    position: relative;
    top: -198; left: -35;
}

img.third {
    position: relative;
    top: -198; left: -35;
}
```

Comment: You haven't added `px` on the *second* and *third*'s top/left values.

Answer (score 1):

Add pixels to all top and left values.

```
top: -75px; left: -1px;
```

Comment: Wow, ha! That was easy, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

you can acheive it by adding a relative class outside the images  and wrap images inside the relative class

HTML

```html
<div class="relative">

 <img class="first" src="assets/icons/Astro_Letter_Logo.png"
 alt="Astro Letter Logo" width="100" height="250">
          
 <img class="second" src="assets/icons/Mail_It_Button.png" alt="Send
 It" width="350" height="300">
          
 <img class="third" src="assets/icons/Address_Found!_Click
 _to_Launch.png" alt="Send It" width="350" height="300">
</div>
```

CSS

```css
    .relative{
        position: relative;
    }
    .relative img{
        position: absolute;
    }
    .relative img:nth-child(1) {
        top: -75px; left: -1px;
       
    }
    
    .relative img:nth-child(2) {

      top: -198px; left: -35px;
    }
    
    .relative img:nth-child(3) {

      top: -198px; left: -35px;
    }
```